# How to manage Focus with States in my custom QML component?

Tags: qt, focus, qml, qt-quick, qtquickcontrols

I´ve created a draggable custom Component in order to manage the geometry of individual Quick Controls Components.

The componet has 2 parts:

- The "Manipulator" which is a draggable and resizable Rectangle
- The inner component which is in the center of the manipulator

Description of the behavior:

1. **No focus**: the default state, the Manipulator is invisible
   and you can only see the inner component
2. **Focused**: When you click the component (or try to drag it) you enter
   this state and the Manipulator becomes visible but you can´t access
   the inner component. Disabled pressing Escape or clicking outside the component (goes to state 1)
3. **Inner Focus**: when you double click on the component The Manipulator
   keeps visible and you can still still resize but the the inner
   component has the main focus (for example a TextEdit now could be
   editable). Disabled pessing Escape (goes to state 2) or clicking outside the component (goes to state 1)

[Example of the Component when the Manipulator area is visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94eOk.png)

The logic of this component would be similar to the logic of a folder in a Desktop Enviroment (except for resizing) The manipulator would be the folder itself and the inner component is its name.

[analogy with folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLmaf.png)

Here I post a simplified version of my manipulator, I´m sure it will help to construct an answer, (I tried a lot of variations for several hours, this is one of those not functional attempts)

```
FocusScope{
    id: root
    width: 175; height: 25;
    focus: true

    states: [
        State {
            name: "noFocus"
            when: !manipulator.activeFocus && !innerComp.activeFocus
            PropertyChanges {
                target: innerComp
                enabled: false
            }
            PropertyChanges {
                target: manipulator
                visible: false
            }
        },

        State {
            name: "focused"
            when: manipulator.activeFocus
            PropertyChanges {
                target: innerComp
                enabled: false
            }
            PropertyChanges {
                target: manipulator
                visible: true
            }
        },
        State {
            name: "innerFocus"
            when: innerComp.activeFocus
            PropertyChanges {
                target: innerComp
                enabled: true
            }
            PropertyChanges {
                target: manipulator
                visible: true
            }
        }
    ]

    //visual area of manipulation (drag, redimension, etc)
    MouseArea{
        id: manipulator
        anchors.fill: parent

        onDoubleClicked: forceActiveFocus(innerComp) //go to state 3 "innerFocus"
        drag.target: manipulator

        Keys.onEscapePressed: forceActiveFocus(root) //I don´t think this is the correct to loose focus but I don´t know how to do that

        Rectangle {
            id: background
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: "lightsteelblue";
        }
    }
    //Inner Component (TextField for example)
    InnerComp {
        id: innerComp
        anchors.fill: parent

        Keys.onEscapePressed: forceActiveFocus(manipulator) //return state 2 "focused"
    }
}
```

Comment: I have found the built in focus to be severely lacking, I usually have the focus fixed at a single item, which acts as an event dispatcher to a number of different selection managers. That's just my use case thou, your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution, as someone in a qt forum sugested:

> *Maybe reverse the dependency, i.e. make the focus depend on the state, not the state depend on the focus?*

So I changed my code and now it works!

I post the solution here for those who could be interested in it (as I said this is a simplified version of the real code):

```
Item {
    id: root
    width: 175; height: 25;

    states: [
        State {
            name: "noFocus"

            PropertyChanges {
                target: innerComp; enabled: false
            }
            PropertyChanges {
                target: background; visible: false
            }
            PropertyChanges {
                target: manipulator; focus: true
            }
        },

        State {
            name: "focused"

            PropertyChanges {
                target: innerComp; enabled: false
            }
            PropertyChanges {
                target: background; visible: true
            }
            PropertyChanges {
                target: manipulator; focus: true
            }
        },
        State {
            name: "innerFocus"

            PropertyChanges {
                target: innerComp; enabled: true
            }
            PropertyChanges {
                target: background; visible: true
            }
            PropertyChanges {
                target: manipulator; focus: true
            }
        }
    ]
    state: "noFocus"

    //visual area of manipulation (drag, redimension, etc)
    MouseArea{
        id: manipulator
        anchors.fill: parent

        onPressed: {
            root.state = "focused"
            forceActiveFocus(manipulator) //this prevents loosing focus in some especific situations
        }
        onDoubleClicked: root.state = "innerFocus"

        Keys.onEscapePressed: root.state = "noFocus"

    }
    Rectangle {
        id: background
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "lightsteelblue";
    }
    //Inner Component (TextField for example)
    InnerComp {
        id: innerComp
        anchors.fill: parent

        Keys.onEscapePressed: root.state = "focused"
    }
}
```